# How to project a chessboard in camera coordinates to real-world coordinates in OpenCV using rvecs and tvecs outputs of cv.calibrateCamera?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, camera-calibration, homography

### Situation

Following the [Camera Calibration tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html) in OpenCV I managed to get an *undistorted image of a checkboard* using `cv.calibrateCamera`:

**Original image:** (named *image.tif* in my computer)

[image]

**Code:**

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((12*13,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:12,0:13].T.reshape(-1,2)
# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

img = cv.imread('image.tif')
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Find the chess board corners
ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray, (12,13), None)
# If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)

if ret == True:
    objpoints.append(objp)
    corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray,corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
    imgpoints.append(corners)
    # Draw and display the corners
    cv.drawChessboardCorners(img, (12,13), corners2, ret)
    cv.imshow('img', img)
    cv.waitKey(2000)

cv.destroyAllWindows()

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)

#Plot undistorted 
h,  w = img.shape[:2]
newcameramtx, roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w,h), 1, (w,h))

dst = cv.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
# crop the image
x, y, w, h = roi
dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(dst)
plt.savefig("undistorted.png", dpi = 300)
plt.close()
```

**Undistorted image:**

[image]

The undistorted image indeed has straight lines. However, in order to test the calibration procedure **I would like to further transform the image into real-world coordinates using the `rvecs` and `tvecs` outputs of `cv.calibrateCamera`**. From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga3207604e4b1a1758aa66acb6ed5aa65d):

> - **rvecs:** Output vector of rotation vectors (Rodrigues ) estimated for each pattern view (e.g. std::vector<cv::Mat>>). That is, **each i-th rotation vector together with the corresponding i-th translation vector** (see the next output parameter description) **brings the calibration pattern from the object coordinate space (in which object points are specified) to the camera coordinate space**. In more technical terms, the tuple of the i-th rotation and translation vector performs a change of basis from object coordinate space to camera coordinate space. Due to its duality, **this tuple is equivalent to the position of the calibration pattern with respect to the camera coordinate space.**
> - **tvecs:**   Output vector of translation vectors estimated for each pattern view, see parameter describtion above.

**Question: How can I manage this?** It would be great if the answers include a working code that outputs the transformed image.

---

### Expected output

The image I expect should look something like this, where the red coordinates correspond to the real-world coordinates of the checkboard (notice the checkboard is a rectangle in this projection):
[image]

---

### What I have tried

Following the comment of @Christoph Rackwitz, I found [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/2737/60285), where they explain the **homography matrix H** that relates the 3D real world coordinates (of the chessboard) to the 2D image coordinates is given by:

`H = K [R1 R2 t]`

where `K` is the camera calibration matrix, `R1` and `R2` are the first two columns of the rotational matrix and `t` is the translation vector.

I tried to calculate this from:

- `K` we already have it as the `mtx` from `cv.calibrateCamera`.
- `R1` and `R2` from `rvecs` after converting it to a rotational matrix (because it is given in [Rodrigues decomposition](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga61585db663d9da06b68e70cfbf6a1eac)): `cv.Rodrigues(rvecs[0])[0]`.
- `t` should be `tvecs`.

In order to calculate the homography from the image coordinates to the 3D real world coordinates then I use the inverse of H.

Finally I use `cv.warpPerspective` to display the projected image.

**Code**:

```py
R = cv.Rodrigues(rvecs[0])[0]
tvec = tvecs[0].squeeze()
H = np.dot(mtx, np.concatenate((R[:,:2], tvec[:,None]), axis = 1) )/tvec[-1] 
plt.imshow(cv.warpPerspective(dst, np.linalg.inv(H), (dst.shape[1], dst.shape[0])))
```

But this does not work, I find the following picture:
[image]

**Any ideas where the problem is?**

---

Related questions:

- [How do I obtain the camera world position from calibrateCamera results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32849373/12131616)
- [Homography from 3D plane to plane parallel to image plane](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39111423/12131616)
- [OpenCV Camera Calibration mathematical background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56732677/12131616)
- [Coordinate transformation in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23616768/12131616)
- [transform 3d camera coordinates to 3d real world coordinates with opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25199908/12131616)

Comment: you don't need skimage for this. OpenCV (and numpy) comes with all the tools. rvec and tvec give you the "real world" pose of the checkerboard. you could compose some 4x4 matrices and then drop that down to a 3x3 homography. or just take the screen-space points of the four outermost corner points of the board, and send that into getPerspectiveTransform, then warpPerspective. -- I'm not awake enough yet to give you specific API calls.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I tried to follow your indications but I am not able to obtain the correct display. If you have any ideas where I might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I did not manage to achieve it with the outputs of `cv.calibrateCamera` but instead I did something simple inspired by @Ann Zen answer. In case it may help someone I will just post it here.

I transform both the **image** and **some data points in the image** to the new coordinates given by the **chessboard reference frame** using only the **four corner points.**

**Input:**

`undistorted.png`

[image]

**Code:**

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

image = cv.imread('undistorted.png')

#Paint some points in blue
points = np.array([[200, 300], [400, 300], [500, 200]])
for i in range(len(points)):
    cv.circle(image, tuple(points[i].astype('int64')), radius=0, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=10)
cv.imwrite('undistorted_withPoints.png', image)

#Put pixels of the chess corners: top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left.
cornerPoints = np.array([[127, 58], [587, 155], [464, 437], [144,344]], dtype='float32')

#Find base of the rectangle given by the chess corners
base = np.linalg.norm(cornerPoints[1] - cornerPoints[0] )

#Height has 11 squares while base has 12 squares.
height = base/12*11

#Define new corner points from base and height of the rectangle
new_cornerPoints = np.array([[0, 0], [int(base), 0], [int(base), int(height)], [0, int(height)]], dtype='float32')

#Calculate matrix to transform the perspective of the image
M = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(cornerPoints, new_cornerPoints)

new_image = cv.warpPerspective(image, M, (int(base), int(height)))

#Function to get data points in the new perspective from points in the image
def calculate_newPoints(points, M):
    new_points = np.einsum('kl, ...l->...k', M,  np.concatenate([points, np.broadcast_to(1, (*points.shape[:-1], 1)) ], axis = -1) )
    return new_points[...,:2] / new_points[...,2][...,None]

new_points = calculate_newPoints(points, M)

#Paint new data points in red
for i in range(len(new_points)):
    cv.circle(new_image, tuple(new_points[i].astype('int64')), radius=0, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=5)

cv.imwrite('new_undistorted.png', new_image)
```

**Outputs:**

`undistorted_withPoints.png`

[image]

`new_undistorted.png`

[image]

**Explanation:**

- I paint some data points in the original picture that I also want to transform.
- With another program I look for the pixels of the corners of the chess (I skip the outer rows and columns).
- I calculate the height and base in pixels of the rectangle defined by the corners.
- I define from the rectangle the new corners in the chessboard coordinates.
- I calculate the matrix M to do the perspective transformation.
- I do the transformation for the image and for the data points following the documentation of [cv.warpPerspective](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87):

[image]

- I paint the transformed data points in red.

Answer (score 1):

Every camera has its own [Intrinsic parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning) connecting 2D image coordinates with 3D real-world. You should solve a branch of linear equations to find them out. Or look at cameras specification parameters, provided by manufacturers. 
Furthermore, if you want to warp your surface to be parallel to the image border use homography transformations. You need the [projective one](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_transform_types.html#projective-transformation-homographies).  `scikit-image` has prepaired [tools](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_geometric.html#parameter-estimation) for parameter estimation.

Comment: `cv.calibrateCamera` already gives the intrinsic parameters: in my example, they are the `mtx` and `dist` values. Ok thank you, I will check `scikit-image`. However, the idea is to do this transformation in order to verify that the calibration has been done properly (if the checkboard is not parallel to the border of the image, it means the calibration is not too good).

Comment: @Puco4, what do you mean under not parallel? You have detected your keypoints, just check then if 2 lines throught them are parallel to the axes

Comment: I mean that if these keypoints are not properly placed in the checkboard and you try to project the image from these keypoints reference frame, you would see the checkboard not parallel to the borders of the image. I would like to visualize how the image looks under this transformation and if you can recover a nice rectangular 2D checkboard. But maybe is not easy to do it with opencv. I assumed you could do this rotating and transforming the image with `vecs` and `tvecs` outputs of `cv.calibrateCamera`.

Answer (score 1):

#### The Concept

Detect the corners of the chessboard using the `cv2.findChessboardCorners()` method. Then, define an array for the destination point for each corner point in the image. Use the triangle warping technique to warp the image from the chessboard corner points to the points in the array defined for the destination locations.

#### The Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def triangles(points):
    points = np.where(points, points, 1)
    subdiv = cv2.Subdiv2D((*points.min(0), *points.max(0)))
    for pt in points:
        subdiv.insert(tuple(map(int, pt)))
    for pts in subdiv.getTriangleList().reshape(-1, 3, 2):
        yield [np.where(np.all(points == pt, 1))[0][0] for pt in pts]

def crop(img, pts):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(pts)
    img_cropped = img[y: y + h, x: x + w]
    pts[:, 0] -= x
    pts[:, 1] -= y
    return img_cropped, pts

def warp(img1, img2, pts1, pts2):
    img2 = img2.copy()
    for indices in triangles(pts1):
        img1_cropped, triangle1 = crop(img1, pts1[indices])
        img2_cropped, triangle2 = crop(img2, pts2[indices])
        transform = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(triangle1), np.float32(triangle2))
        img2_warped = cv2.warpAffine(img1_cropped, transform, img2_cropped.shape[:2][::-1], None, cv2.INTER_LINEAR, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101)
        mask = np.zeros_like(img2_cropped)
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, np.int32(triangle2), (1, 1, 1), 16, 0)
        img2_cropped *= 1 - mask
        img2_cropped += img2_warped * mask
    return img2

img = cv2.imread("image.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (12 ,13), None)
corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)

x, y, w, h, r, c = 15, 40, 38, 38, 12, 13
pts1 = np.int32(corners2.squeeze())
arr2 = np.tile(np.arange(c), r).reshape((r, c))
arr1 = np.tile(np.arange(r), c).reshape((c, r))
arr = np.dstack((arr1[:, ::-1] * h + y, arr2.T * w + x))
pts2 = arr.reshape((r * c, 2))

cv2.imshow("result", warp(img, np.zeros_like(img), pts1, pts2))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

#### The Output

Here is the output image:

[image]

For the input image of:

[image]

#### The Explanation

1. Import the necessary libraries:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

2. Define a function, `triangles`, that will take in an array of coordinates, `points`, and yield lists of 3 indices of the array for triangles that will cover the area of the original array of coordinates:

```
def triangles(points):
    points = np.where(points, points, 1)
    subdiv = cv2.Subdiv2D((*points.min(0), *points.max(0)))
    for pt in points:
        subdiv.insert(tuple(map(int, pt)))
    for pts in subdiv.getTriangleList().reshape(-1, 3, 2):
        yield [np.where(np.all(points == pt, 1))[0][0] for pt in pts]
```

3. Define a function, `crop`, that will take in an image array, `img`, and an array of three coordinates, `pts`. It will return a rectangular segment of the image just large enough to fit the triangle formed by the three point, and return the array of three coordinates transferred to the top-left corner of image:

```
def crop(img, pts):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(pts)
    img_cropped = img[y: y + h, x: x + w]
    pts[:, 0] -= x
    pts[:, 1] -= y
    return img_cropped, pts
```

4. Define a function, `warp`, that will take in 2 image arrays, `img1` and `img2`, and 2 arrays of coordinates, `pts1` and `pts2`. It will utilize the `triangles` function defined before iterate through the triangles from the first array of coordinates, the `crop` function defined before to crop both images at coordinates corresponding to the triangle indices and use the `cv2.warpAffine()` method to warp the image at the current triangle of the iterations:

```
def warp(img1, img2, pts1, pts2):
    img2 = img2.copy()
    for indices in triangles(pts1):
        img1_cropped, triangle1 = crop(img1, pts1[indices])
        img2_cropped, triangle2 = crop(img2, pts2[indices])
        transform = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(triangle1), np.float32(triangle2))
        img2_warped = cv2.warpAffine(img1_cropped, transform, img2_cropped.shape[:2][::-1], None, cv2.INTER_LINEAR, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101)
        mask = np.zeros_like(img2_cropped)
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, np.int32(triangle2), (1, 1, 1), 16, 0)
        img2_cropped *= 1 - mask
        img2_cropped += img2_warped * mask
    return img2
```

5. Read in the image of the distorted chessboard, convert it to grayscale and detect the corners of the chessboard:

```
img = cv2.imread("image.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (12 ,13), None)
corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
```

6. Define an array of the destination points for each corner detected. If you plot each corner along with their corresponding index in the array, you will see that they are in this order:

[image]

So our destination array must be in that order, or we will end up with unreadable results. The `x, y, w, h, r, c` below will be the destination array of coordinates' top-left `x, y` position, each square's width & height, and the number of rows & columns of points in the board:

```
x, y, w, h, r, c = 15, 40, 38, 38, 12, 13
pts1 = np.int32(corners2.squeeze())
arr2 = np.tile(np.arange(c), r).reshape((r, c))
arr1 = np.tile(np.arange(r), c).reshape((c, r))
arr = np.dstack((arr1[:, ::-1] * h + y, arr2.T * w + x))
pts2 = arr.reshape((r * c, 2))
```

6. Finally, show the warped part of the image on a blank image:

```
cv2.imshow("result", warp(img, np.zeros_like(img), pts1, pts2))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Though my question is more about if it is possible to use only the outputs of `cv.calibrateCamera` (tvecs and rvecs parameters) in order to do the transformation and check if the calibration has been done properly.

Comment: @Puco4 I see, I might look into that. Also, good luck and cheers!